# Symfony2 form where the data objects doesn't match exactly what needs to be filled in

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

We have a monitoring service where our monitor units keep an eye on certain machines.

I'm creating a form to register a new machine in Symfony2.

So we have the **machine entity**:

- id
- machine name
- monitor id

And the **monitor entity**:

- id
- serialnumber
- ...

For a new machine, the customer needs to fill the **form** with:

- machine name
- serialnumber of attached monitor
- ...

Now, if I make a form with, as data backing, a machine entity, I have no 'field' in which to ask for the serial number. Symfony doesn't allow it, since the backing entity doesn't have a field named 'serial number'.

How can I:

- ask for the serial number while there is no such field in the backing entity
- if I get the serial number, how do I link it up with it's internal id to persist with the entity once the data is validated and bound

I figure I can:

- make a form without an object behind it, as described by @weaverryan in this excellent article: http://knplabs.com/en/blog-csi/symfony-validators-standalone - this way I do the persisting myself, but I need separate constraints for my custom form, and for my machine entity, which is a pity.
- provide some kind of link so that Symfony knows where to get the fact that a serialnumber field exists, and what it's constraints are. Perhaps by defining a relation? Tbh I was hoping to avoid relations in my entity code, because I've seen quite a few problems arise from it on the mailinglist, but maybe I have no choice :-)
- anything else?

I hope I'm explaining this right. I think many have had to solve this. I think I'm just looking over some very standard Symfony functionality, just because I'm not sure what it's called :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you *should* be using relationship - i.e. Machine has one monitory. I think people have problems with this because when you're used to thinking about things in terms of "id"s and foreign keys, thinking about relationships in a fully object-oriented way is new :).

So, assuming your Machine is related to Monitor, you can now create a MachineType that embeds a MonitorType (which would be a form with the serialnumber field in it). Then, your constraints for serialnumber on your Monitor class would be used when the compound form is submitted.

By default, when you bind all of this, it'll create a new Machine object, with a new Monitor object available via $machine->getMonitor(). If you persist, this will be two inserts. However, I'm guessing that you'd rather lookup the monitor by its serialnumber and use that existing monitor, right? To do so is easy, just short-circuit things after you bind your form.

```
$form = new MachineType();
$form->bindRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $machine = $form->getData();
    $serialNumber = $machine->getMonitor->getSerialNumber();

    $existingMonitor = $em
        ->getRepository('YourBundle:Monitor')
        ->findOneBy(array('serialNumber' => $serialNumber));
    if ($existingMonitory) {
        $machine->setMonitor($existingMonitor);
    }

    $em->persist($machine);
    $em->persist($machine->getMonitor());
    $em->flush();

    // ...
}
```

So, that's the idea. Biggest thing is that by not using relationships, you're putting yourself at a disadvantage. You see, by embedding these two forms together, you really *do* have natural access to the serialnumber field.

Good luck!

Comment: Aim, shoot, score. Thanks Ryan!

Comment: Sort of a related question @weaverryan: I embedded the MonitorType in my MachineType form for my frontend registration ability (which works great, thanks). Now say that I need a similar form in my backend, with an extra field besides serialNumber, for example activationDate. I would add it to the MonitorType class as an extra field. But then it also gets printed in my original form, since it embeds the whole thing. How do I prevent this? Do I create another formtype (MonitorBackendType, maybe extends), or do I decide in the template which fields I show?

Comment: @Dieter, you should probably add this as a second question or amend your first.

Comment: @Josiah: You are right, thanks. I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724564/how-to-re-use-forms-with-some-fields-left-out-in-symfony2

Comment: @weaverryan: This question has been a while, but I find myself looking back at this code with a small problem. The code works great when using it for a new entity, but when I edit an existing machine with a new monitor (I edit the serialnumber in the form), it not only points the machine to a new monitor, but also changes the serialnumber of the now ex-monitor. I think this happens when binding the request to the object, but I'm not sure how to nicely undo it before flushing?

Answer (score 4):

I tackled this problem recently, by creating a custom form type (in my case called a "selector") which has a datatransformer attached to it, which returns the monitor by serial:

The Machine type:

```
class MachineType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('monitor', 'monitor_selector_type');
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'machine;
    }
}
```

The monitor selector type (Eventually this will simply be a text field (the default type parent is "text"), in which you will enter the monitor serial. The field will display an error if a non existing serial was entered.

```
class MonitorSelectorType extends AbstractType {
    private $doctrine

    public function __construct(Registry $doctrine) {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
        $transformer = new MonitorToSerialTransformer($this->doctrine->getEntityManager());
        $builder->appendClientTransformer($transformer);
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array(
            'invalid_message'=>'The selected monitor does not exist',
            'error_bubbling'=>false
        );
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'machine;
    }
}
```

This class transforms the serial to an actual Monitor and an actual Monitor to a serial

```
class MonitorToSerialTransformer {
    private $em

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function transform($val) {
        if (null === $val) {
            return '';
        }
        return $val->getSerial();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($val) {
        if (!$val) {
            return null;
        }
        $monitor = $this->em->getRepository('xBundle:Monitor')->findOneBy(array('serial' => $val));
        if (null === $monitor) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException('A monitor with serial '.$val.' does not exist!');
        }
        return $monitor;
    }
}
```

finally, register the MonitorSelectorType in your service container with id "monitor_selector_type" and tag "form.type" and have doctrine injected to it.

Now it will be very easy at any random place in your application to use this selector type to select a monitor by ID. No logic has to be added to your Controller at all.

If you want a new monitor to be created when an unknown serial is entered, you can instantiate it rather than throwing the TransformationFailedException, and even persist it to your entity manager if the machine has no cascing options for the monitor.

Regards,
Bart

Comment: That's quite an awesome explanation. I didn't even knew about the concept of transforms yet, and they seem quite useful for many parts of my application. I'm going to try it out asap. Thanks a lot m8!

Comment: Alright, I took a shot at this and it's mostly going great. One small remark that you might edit: the transformer needs to implement the Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface interface.
One question though: I can get the monitor 'form' to show up, but without the textfield :) Just the title really, if I do form_rest. Where does one 'set' that the monitor_selector_type must be displayed as text? In any case, thanks already :)

Comment: Hi Dieter, There's a little mistake in the code. The MonitorSelectorType should override the getParent() method as follows: `public function getParent() { return 'text'; }`. You are right about the interface, I forgot that as well. I made a pull request for the symfony docs https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/820 explaining the use of data transformers

Comment: Thanks a lot Bart, that explains it perfectly. If I ever meet you irl, I owe you a beer ;-)