# How to re-use forms with some fields left out in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, code-reuse

I am using embedded forms to be able to make a registration form, which holds fields of several related entities. As explained to me in my question over here:
[Symfony2 form where the data objects doesn't match exactly what needs to be filled in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648117/symfony2-form-where-the-data-objects-doesnt-match-exactly-what-needs-to-be-fille/7650072#7650072)

This works just fine. But say I want to re-use one of the forms that I embedded, but leave some of the fields out.
Then what are my options?

- Do I create an extra formType which extends the original one?
- Do I decide in the view to leave some fields out?

This doesn't feel like a view decision in my opinion though. And extending for each different use case feels like a bad re-use practice to me.
How are other people solving this?

Thanks,

Dieter

Comment: You should also look into inherit data, which lets you combine a base form with two custom forms. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution is to create a base abstract Type and let your Types extend it. Here's a short example:

```php
namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

abstract FooBaseType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Add all fields common for your other types.
    }
}
```

Now you can just extend it an include the missing fields

```php
namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

class ExampleType extends FooBaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        // Your missing fields
    }
}
```

Comment: Idd, I see no other option. Seems like a tad unhandy to me, but at least someone agrees with me that this is the way to go :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

see this github pull request: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/765

it seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Idd it does. Going to keep an eye on that one. Thanks again Bart :-)